# Use rsync with passthru() in a php program

Tags: php, command-line, cmd, rsync

I have a very simple php program that I am running with a cron.

```
<?php
$cmd="rsync  --ignore-existing -raz --progress /home/account1/public_html/inventory/images home/account2/public_html/inventory/";
passthru($cmd);
exit(0);?>
```

Both account1 and account2 are on my dedicated server. The program is run on account2

That command runs perfectly when run manually. But when I run the program it fails. Do I need to include the username and password of account1? How would I do that?

Comment: can you try `exec` or `shell_exec`